# Problem with ScriptManager and ASP.NET AJAX Timer

Tags: asp.net, timer, scriptmanager

I'm having a serious problem with my ASP.NET AJAX application.

There is a javascript function in my application needs to be executed after the Timer_Tick event. Here's the code behind:

```
void SetValues()
   {
   try 
   {
   StringBuilder sbScript = new StringBuilder();
   sbScript.Append("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>");
   sbScript.Append("function UpdateValue() {");
   for (int j = 0; j < iTotalDevices; j++)
   {
   sbScript.Append("setElementValue(" + j.ToString() + "," + DevicesInfo[j].X.ToString() + "," + DevicesInfo[j].Y.ToString() + "," + iStatus.ToString() + "," + DevicesInfo[j].DeviceID.ToString() + ");");
   }
   sbScript.Append("}");
   sbScript.Append("</script>");
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", sbScript.ToString(), false);
   }
   catch 
   { }
   }

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///This function will get latest values from database
    GetNewData();
    SetValues();
}
```

When I call the javascript function 'UpdateValue' for the first time (at onload page event), it works correctly. But after the Timer_Tick event, it does nothing. This is the HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function PageLoad() {
///Call function for the first time and it works
UpdateValue();
}

function setElementValue(index, value1, value2, value3...) {
///Set value for each element in object array
}

</script>
<body onload="PageLoad()">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="30000">
</body>
```

What's the problem with the ScriptManager or the Timer_Tick event?

Many thanks,

Comment: The Timer1 control also triggers an UpdatePanel as expected, except for this java function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're registering the UpdateValue function each time Timer1_Tick executes.

Try changing your SetValues function to this:

```
void SetValues()
{
   try 
   {
       StringBuilder sbScript = new StringBuilder();
       sbScript.Append("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>");
       for (int j = 0; j < iTotalDevices; j++)
       {
       sbScript.Append("setElementValue(" + j.ToString() + "," + DevicesInfo[j].X.ToString() + "," + DevicesInfo[j].Y.ToString() + "," + iStatus.ToString() + "," + DevicesInfo[j].DeviceID.ToString() + ");");
       }
       sbScript.Append("</script>");
       ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), string.Format("myscript{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")), sbScript.ToString(), false);
   }
   catch 
   { }
}
```

EDIT: Notice that I'm using RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of RegisterStartupScript. Also, "myscript" should be a unique key, so I just updated that part.

Comment: Thank you Tchami, I've tried the code snip ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock as your suggestion, but it still did not work.

I also viewed the page source and noticed that the first-time called function has been injected at the end of the page:

<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function UpdateValue() { setElementValue(...); setElementValue(...); etc }
</script>

Comment: So if the next function myscript{0} was registered correctly, it would have been injected at the bottom as well. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You shouldn't inject UpdateValue(). I think that's what is causing the problem. How does the source code look (take a look with Firebug or something similar) like if you inject it as I suggested?

Comment: Hi Tchami, I finally solved my problem. The registered function need a unique name and it must be registered to the Timer control. That's all! Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem, glad you solved it. If you have time, you might want to update your question with the answer so other people may benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my finished code:

```
void SetValues()
   {
   try 
   {
   StringBuilder sbScript = new StringBuilder();
   sbScript.Append("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>");

   sbScript.Append("Sys.Application.add_load(UpdateValue);");

   sbScript.Append("function UpdateValue() {");
   sbScript.Append("Sys.Application.remove_load(UpdateValue);");
   for (int j = 0; j < iTotalDevices; j++)
   {
   sbScript.Append("setElementValue(" + j.ToString() + "," + DevicesInfo[j].X.ToString() + "," + DevicesInfo[j].Y.ToString() + "," + iStatus.ToString() + "," + DevicesInfo[j].DeviceID.ToString() + ");");
   }
   sbScript.Append("}");
   sbScript.Append("</script>");
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Time1.GetType(), "UpdateValue", sbScript.ToString(), false);
   }
   catch 
   { }
   }
```